# How to operate on object based on string

Tags: javascript, string, object

JS noob here. If I have a string, how can I call an attribute from an object which has the same name as the string?

```
var carrot = {
    'vitaminA': 150,
    'vitaminC': 100
};

var cucumber = {
    'vitaminA': 10,
    'vitaminC': 12

};

var vegetable = 'cucumber'
alert(vegetable.vitaminC) // this doesn't work
```

Note: this is a simplified version of the problem I'm working on, so I can't simply say alert(cucumber.vitaminC) -- I have to operate on the object based on the string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 3):

You can have it like:

```
window[vegetable].vitaminC
```

But I highly suggest containing these guys in an object that is not the global object `window`:

```
var vegetables = {
  cucumber : {
    vitaminA: 10,
    vitaminC: 12
  },
  carrot : {
    vitaminA: 150,
    vitaminC: 100
  }
};

var vegetable = 'cucumber';
alert(vegetables[vegetable].vitaminC);
```

Comment: +1: beat me to it. Although personally I like me some semicolons :)

Comment: Thanks, why do you suggest not containing it in the global object window?

Comment: @BenDavidow because `window` is the global object, and a good practice is to **not** "pollute" the global space with a lot of stuff. There are a lot of reasons why.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you know the scope. If the scope is global, you can access it like this:

```
var vegetable = window['cucumber'];
alert(vegetable.vitaminC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your structure a little bit to get your objects out of the global scope. You can do this by simply adding a new object to contain your vegetables:

```
var vegetables = {
    carrot: {
        'vitaminA': 150,
        'vitaminC': 100
    },
    cucumber: {
        'vitaminA': 10,
        'vitaminC': 12
    }
};
```

And then you'd be able to access your properties by name (with a string) using `[]` notation:

```
vegetables['cucumber'].vitaminC; // 12
```

Or

```
vegetables['cucumber']['vitaminC']; // 12
```

Comment: They don't need to change the structure to access the properties. Although I do agree they should change the structure :)